# Fastest way to output on screen?

Tags: c++, buffer, screen

I'm trying a snake game on the console, but `cout` is way too slow for the game to be interactive. It also flickers like crazy. Can you recommend the best way of output on the screen? Maybe something called screen buffer? How do I do that?

Comment: Use `ncurses` library.  It is specific to address that subject.  There's a `ncurses` library for `cygwin` in Windows at least, but probably you can get a version to run on your windows environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you're making an application that's meant to run with graphics in the console, the best and most standard way to do it is with the ncurses library! It has underlying access to the terminal's buffer and it's what vim uses!

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/getting-started-ncurses

Comment: I'm using Windows. Is there a Windows option?

Comment: @AndreasKostas, sure!! you can use CygWin's version, or you can get a version running on windows for sure.